# Anonymous Login & Username: Firebase + AuthUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am fairly new to Firebase and Firebase Auth UI and got two questions:

1. I am using Firebase Auth UI for a simple login activity. How can I add a anonymous login option to the screen? The option is activated in the Firebase console.
2. How can I add a username / nickname to the user? It is okay to add it after the registration completed, but which method do I have to call?

Here is my Code:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // User is already signed in
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // User isn't already signed in
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setProviders(
                                    AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                    AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                            .setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // user is signed in!
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error during login :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all possible Firebase login implementations from the [link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth).

> **Q1.** I am using Firebase Auth UI for a simple login activity. How can I add a anonymous login option to the screen? The option is
>   activated in the Firebase console.

../AnonymousAuthActivity.java

> **Q2.** How can I add a username / nickname to the user? It is okay to add it after the registration completed, but which method do I have to
>   call?

.../EmailPasswordActivity.java

Comment: Alright, ty for the answer, but I maybe misunderstood something.. I am not designing the Login-UI by myself, I am using the prebuilded UI AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().....

Comment: Aha sorry i missed the point. AuthUI does not support anonymous login. And for the username when you set AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER a username and password fields must appear but i havnt try it yet

Comment: Alright^^ Last question: How do I set the username the user signs in by Facebook / Google? Is there a "Firebaseuser.getInstance().setUsername("MyUsername")" function? ;D

Comment: That s not the point of using Google or FB login. You already have username and password and you need to login with ur fb or google credentials. And if you wanna know user data when logged in, auth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() gives the user display name. Other available methods for the user listed here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser